# How to change spacing and labeling in tikz group plot?

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to learn how to change my labels from generic `(A)` to `(My special label)` individually for each graph as well as create additional space so that the graphs and their respective labels don't collide into each other.  Here's my code (the automatic labeling is where I have `\nextgroupplot [auto title]`) :

```
    \documentclass[aps,amsmath,amssymb,letter,scriptaddress,twocolumn, prl,showkeys]     {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots,alphalph}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
%\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
%\usepackage[colorlinks,hyperindex]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
auto title/.style={     title=(\AlphAlph{\pgfplots@group@current@plot})
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
      \begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group size=3 by 2,
    ylabels at=edge left
},
      view={0}{90},
      width=5cm,
      height=5cm,
      scale only axis,
      xmin=0, xmax=3,
      ymin=-8, ymax=0,
xlabel={x},
    ylabel={$y$},
      name=plot2,
      unbounded coords=jump]
    ]
        \nextgroupplot [auto title]    
\addplot [only marks, mark=o, color=red,auto title] table{
1       -2.5
2       -3.3
3       -3.4
};
\addplot [domain=1:3, color=black,auto title] {-0.0538*x-2.8234};
    \nextgroupplot [auto title]    
\addplot [only marks, mark=o, color=red,auto title] table{
1       -2.5
2       -3.3
3       -3.4
};
\addplot [domain=1:3, color=black,auto title] {-0.0538*x-2.8234};
        \nextgroupplot[auto title]         
\addplot [only marks, mark=o, color=red] table{
    1       -2.900422094
    2       -3.244193633
    3       -3.283414346
};
\addplot [domain=4:6, color=black] {-0.0333*x-3.1637};
        \nextgroupplot[auto title]         
\addplot [only marks, mark=o, color=red] table{
4       -4.199705078
5       -4.674163057
6       -4.674163057
};
\addplot [domain=4:6, color=black] {-0.0749*x-1.7959};
 \end{groupplot}
    \node (A) at ([yshift=0.5cm]group c1r1.north west) {\color{red} A};
    \node (B) at ([yshift=0.5cm]group c2r1.north west) {\color{red} B};
    \node (C) at ([yshift=0.5cm]group c3r1.north west) {\color{red} C};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My caption} 
 \label{myfig}
  \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the desired title by deleting the `auto title` style and using the `title=<text>` option to `\nextgroup`; using `horizontal sep` and/or `vertical sep` for the `group style` style, you can control the horizontal or vertical separation between plots. A complete example with a generous vertical spacing just for illustration purposes:

```
\documentclass[aps,amsmath,amssymb,letter,scriptaddress,twocolumn, prl,showkeys]     {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots,alphalph}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
%\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
%\usepackage[colorlinks,hyperindex]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
%\pgfplotsset{
%auto title/.style={     title=(\AlphAlph{\pgfplots@group@current@plot})
%    }
%}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
      \begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group size=3 by 2,vertical sep=80pt,
    ylabels at=edge left
},
      view={0}{90},
      width=5cm,
      height=5cm,
      scale only axis,
      xmin=0, xmax=3,
      ymin=-8, ymax=0,
xlabel={x},
    ylabel={$y$},
      name=plot2,
      unbounded coords=jump]
    ]
        \nextgroupplot [title=(My special title)]    
\addplot [only marks, mark=o, color=red,title=(A first special title)] table{
1       -2.5
2       -3.3
3       -3.4
};
\addplot [domain=1:3, color=black] {-0.0538*x-2.8234};
    \nextgroupplot [title=(Another special title)]    
\addplot [only marks, mark=o, color=red] table{
1       -2.5
2       -3.3
3       -3.4
};
\addplot [domain=1:3, color=black] {-0.0538*x-2.8234};
        \nextgroupplot[title=(And another special title)]         
\addplot [only marks, mark=o, color=red] table{
    1       -2.900422094
    2       -3.244193633
    3       -3.283414346
};
\addplot [domain=4:6, color=black] {-0.0333*x-3.1637};
        \nextgroupplot[title=(Yet another special title)]         
\addplot [only marks, mark=o, color=red] table{
4       -4.199705078
5       -4.674163057
6       -4.674163057
};
\addplot [domain=4:6, color=black] {-0.0749*x-1.7959};
 \end{groupplot}
    \node (A) at ([yshift=0.5cm]group c1r1.north west) {\color{red} A};
    \node (B) at ([yshift=0.5cm]group c2r1.north west) {\color{red} B};
    \node (C) at ([yshift=0.5cm]group c3r1.north west) {\color{red} C};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My caption} 
 \label{myfig}
  \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]